# PHP Script Evaluation Differences Between Apache & IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, uri

Today I discovered a major difference between the way Apache and IIS evaluate URIs with PHP scripts. I would like to know if there is a name for this behavior, and whether I can turn it on or off in each brand of server.

**I tested this on Windows 10, with IIS 10 64-bit and Apache 2.4 64-bit (from ApacheHaus).**

Consider the following URL:

> example.com/folder/**script_A.php**/folder/**script_B.php**

### IIS Behavior

In IIS, a PHP script is only executed if the script name is at the end of the URI. So, script_B is executed, and the segment "script_A.php" is assumed to just be a folder name.

### Apache Behavior

However, in Apache, the first PHP script found in the URI is the one to get executed, even if it is found in the middle of the URI. So, script_A is executed, and everything after "script_A.php" is just extra URI information to do with as you please.

### Why does this matter?

This affects the way some PHP frameworks route their URLs. In CodeIgniter, for example, URLs always begin with "index.php", and the rest of the URL segments are used for model/view/controller logic.

Such a URL in CodeIgniter looks like this:

> example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes

Because of this, CodeIgniter's default routing mechanism won't work in IIS, because IIS only executes the file name that's found at the end of the URL (so in this example, IIS looks for a file or folder called "shoes"). To get CodeIgniter to work in IIS, you have to turn on URL Rewriting behavior in web.config that directs every request to "index.php".

**What is the name of behavior, and how can I modify this behavior in both servers (if possible)?**

Comment: On which OS are you running Apache? I assume you run IIS on Windows.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I updated the question with that info. Windows 10, with IIS 10 64-bit and Apache 2.4 64-bit (from ApacheHaus)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I suspect that it has to do with how files/directories work under linux, Apache probably tries to emulate this behaviour under Windows. The obvious question to you is: Why would you give a directory a `.php` extension, or the same name as a php script? I've struggled with similar issues in Apache, but only when I used .htaccess rewrites.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just added a section called "Why does this matter?" in the question; it might give you a new perspective on it. Basically, it has the potential to affect the way PHP frameworks function in IIS if you aren't using URL Rewrite

Comment: That is a useful addition. So you want IIS to behave like Apache. I don't know how to do that. I did find something like this: https://gist.github.com/wmandai/d28cc45f10a19eec0fcb No idea if that's useful. PS: Could you change your name from 'user3163495' to something else? Now we cannot select you when we use '@', for some reason.

Comment: Forget that last question. I found out that I can never select the '@' for the persons asking the questions, which makes sense, comments are assumed to be directed towards them.